# TFS git compare branch shows a change but files section shows No files have changed

Tags: git, tfs, git-diff

I have two git branches on TFS , when compared shows a change exist but the files section shows `No files have changed.`

But shows one commit in commits section

[image: Files section]

[image: Commit section]